# Django Value Error "The view capstone.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm taking data that the user puts into a form and saving it to the database in Django. When I submit the form, the value actually does save to the database. But I keep getting this error. Not sure how to fix it?

views.py

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form_for_post = {'form': PostForm()}
        return render(request, "capstone/home2.html", form_for_post)
    else: 
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PostForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            place = Location.objects.create(username=request.user, city=city,)
            place.save()
        else:
            return render(request, "capstone/home2.html")
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=500) 
    username = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='author', null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class PostForm(forms.Form):
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Form in html:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <label for="city">City:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: `if form.is_valid():` this if clause, if satisfied, causes the view to not return anything. It seems you don't need the `else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default if request is made it will be a get request so don't need to add `if request.method == 'GET'`
so do like this

```
def home(request):
    form_for_post = {'form': PostForm()}
    if request.method == "POST":
       form = PostForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          city = form.cleaned_data['city']
          place = Location.objects.create(username=request.user, city=city,)
          place.save()
          return render(request,"your_page_after_form_successfully_submited")
    return render(request, "capstone/home2.html",form_for_post)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            place = Location.objects.create(username=request.user, city=city,)
            place.save()
        else:
            return render(request, "capstone/home2.html",form)
    form_for_post = {'form': PostForm()}
    return render(request, "capstone/home2.html", form_for_post)
```

try this one